# How do I update a dependency within a package in Xcode using CocoaPods?

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods, podfile, yelp-fusion-api

I've installed CDYelpFusionKit using CocoaPods, but I run into an error 65 since the package uses AlamoFireObjectMapper 5.2.0, which is incompatible with Swift 5. AlamoFireObjectMapper 5.2.1 has been released here https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/releases/tag/5.2.1, but **it hasn't been released on CocoaPods**. I'm trying to figure out how to replace the AlamoFireObjectMapper dependency that comes with the CDYelpFusionKit package with an updated branch from here https://github.com/RomanPodymov/AlamofireObjectMapper. I've tried the following in my podfile, then run pod repo update and pod install:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/RomanPodymov/AlamofireObjectMapper.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Demand' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'CDYelpFusionKit', '~> 1.5.1'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', :git => 'https://github.com/RomanPodymov/AlamofireObjectMapper.git', :branch => 'xcode-10-2-fix'

    end
```

But I get the error:

```
"[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AlamofireObjectMapper":
  In Podfile:
    AlamofireObjectMapper (from `https://github.com/RomanPodymov/AlamofireObjectMapper.git`, branch `xcode-10-2-fix`)

CDYelpFusionKit (= 1.5.1) was resolved to 1.5.1, which depends on AlamofireObjectMapper (= 5.2.0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Update CocoaPods to its newest version

2.) Try to delete your lock file and run pod install after that, usually, it installs way newer versions of everything. Also, if your project is ios 9+, modify your platform to something bigger in yor podfile

*I hope it is obvious but make a copy of your project folder before trying this solution if you are not using any version control or something along the line*